# How to create a helper that I can use inside all the Template.template.events?

Tags: javascript, meteor

For example I have something like this:

**post_form.js:**

```
Template.postForm.events({
  "input #input-content": function() {

    var words, wordsNumber;

    Posts.update(this._id, {
      $set: {
        content: $("#input-content").html()
      }
    });

    words = $("#input-content > p").map(function() {
      $.text(this);
    }).get().join(" ");

    wordsNumber = words.trim().split(" ").length;

    $(".post-words-number").html(wordsNumber);
  }
});
```

**post_list.js:**

```
Template.postList.events({
  "click .open-post": function() {

    var words, wordsNumber;

    if (this.content) {
      $("#input-content").html(this.content);
    } else {
      $("#input-content").html("");
    }

    words = $("#input-content > p").map(function() {
      return $.text(this);
    }).get().join(" ");

    wordsNumber = words.trim().split(" ").length;

    return $(".post-words-number").html(wordsNumber);
  }
});
```

As you can see this:

```
    words = $("#input-content > p").map(function() {
      return $.text(this);
    }).get().join(" ");

    wordsNumber = words.trim().split(" ").length;

    return $(".post-words-number").html(wordsNumber);
```

is repeated twice. How to I create a helper for that piece of code so I can reuse it in those two templates? Where should I place it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you want to! As long as it's on the client side, of course. Files do see each other, so a piece of code written in one file can be accessed from any other.

So, for example:

**/client/app.js**

```
App = {};

App.doSomething = function(template) {
  ...
};
```

**/client/views/post_list.js**

```
Template.post_list.events({
  'click .clickable': function(e, t) {
    App.doSomething(t);
    ...
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't have anything that looks like App. Meteor tells me is not defined. The tree looks like this: `/client/views/application/layout.js` (where I pasted your code) and `/client/views/posts/post_lists.js` (where I want to use it).

Comment: App is an object you make, then you house the code in there that you currently have duplicated. It doesn't have to be called App. You can call it whatever you want.

Comment: @Hubert OG Strange Oh, the problem was that I was using CoffeeScript and I had to do `@App`. Thanks! So defining a `Object = {};` is a must? Why is that?

Comment: No, it's entirely optional. You can have twenty of them if you want, or you can create the function globally: `doSomething = function()...`, or, in your case, `@doSomething = () -> ...`. I've just used the `App` object as an example, as it's generally a better practice to group your code in several meaningful modules rather than creating dozens of global functions. It's less likely to run in naming conflicts down the road.